# $_GET variable cannot identify the first array element

Tags: php, url

$_GET variable cannot identify the first array element.:

I have passed an array in url which looks like this

> http://www.example.com/form.php?action=buy_now&ft=prf&Arrayproducts_id[]=431&products_id[]=432&Arraycart[]=1&cart[]=3&Arrayid[]=431&id[]=432

but when i print the array "products_id" and "cart" by using print_r($_GET), it just display me

```
Array
(
    [0] => 432
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
)
```

now as u can see the url it also contains the value "431" for products_id and "3" for cart
I can see that due to the string "Array" appended to these they are not being accessed, So could someone suggest me how to fix this issue

> **EDIT as per Felix review**

```
for($t=0;$t<4;$t++){

    $proid_30 .= "products_id[".$t."]=".$products_id."&";
        $bucket_30 .= "cart[".$t."]=".$_SESSION['qty_flex'][$t]."&";
        $idproid_30 .= "id[".$t."]=".$products_id."&";

        }
        $idproid_30.=" ";
$idproid_30 = str_replace("& ","",$idproid_30);
        echo "<script>window.location= '/print_ready_form.php?action=buy_now&ft=prf&".$proid_30.$bucket_30.$idproid_30."&osCsid=".$_GET['osCsid']."';</script>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you `echo` an array to create your URL. This does not work:

```
$a = array(1,2);
echo $a;
```

prints

```
Array
```

Can you show the PHP code that generates the URL?

**Update:**

Without more code I can only assume, but I think that `$proid_30`, `$bucket_30` and `$idproid_30` are initialized as **arrays**. Now when you append a string, they are casted to strings:

```
$a = array(1,2);
$a .= 'test';
echo $a;
```

prints

```
Arraytest
```

**Use new variables to build the URL or initialize them as strings**:

E.g.:

```
$product = '';
$cart = '';
$id = '';
for($t=0;$t<4;$t++){
    $product .= "products_id[".$t."]=".$products_id."&";
    $cart .= "cart[".$t."]=".$_SESSION['qty_flex'][$t]."&";
    $id .= "id[".$t."]=".$products_id."&";
}
```

Comment: @OMThe Eternity: Can show more code? This seems to be only a part of it and I cannot find a problem there.

Comment: this is it where the problem is Felix, as u said echo of url is creating the problem.. u r right for that..this is the place we have to make the correction for which i am not aware of

Comment: +1 Been trying to figure this out. But thanks to you, I learnt something new =)

Comment: @OMThe Eternity, the problem is that `$proid_30` has some bad value in it *before* the loop you posted runs. So this loop is fine, the problem lies before this.

Comment: @OMThe Eternity: I think you have a misunderstanding here. You don't create arrays, you create strings that have more a less a special structure.

Comment: Yes U r Right Again :) I misunderstood it... Thank YOU FELIX CAT.. DONT MIND YOUR NAME REMIND ME OF a Video GAME i used to play in my childhood

Answer (score 0):

you can use variable names like "var[]" in a http form. do you need to use only get method? try post

Answer (score 0):

Its only displaying the `432` for `products_id` because the only other products_id in the link is called `Arrayproducts_id`.

You will need to rename this back to `products_id` =)

Unless you want to call Arrayproducts_id ofcourse.

Comment: thats what the proble is i am not passing any of this key called "Arrayproducts_id" I want to remove this "Array" string attached in url

Comment: Are you able to edit the link which set this URL in the first place?

Comment: Felix seems to have beaten me to the problem =)

Answer (score 0):

First product Id was named as "Arrayproducts_id". So you can get by printing "Arrayproducts_id"